# How to size in bytes for a transaction using BitcoinJ

Tags: transactions, bitcoinj

The calculation of a transaction fee uses fee/kb. So how do I get the size in bytes for a transaction using BitcoinJ?

```
SendRequest req = SendRequest.to(address, value);

req.feePerKb = Coin.parseCoin("0.0000100");

Wallet.SendResult result = kit.wallet().sendCoins(req);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know the size in bytes of a transaction without knowing the inputs to the transaction. Just knowing the amount you want to transfer and just the output does not tell you anything.

Using the `sendCoins()` method and setting `feePerKb` in your `SendRequest` should create a transaction that pays the specified fee rate. If you want to get the transaction details after you send, the `SendResult` that you get has a field named `tx` which is a `Transaction` object. You can then get the necessary information from there.

If you want to know the size before you send, then you need to craft the transaction yourself as `sendCoins()` will automatically create and send the transaction for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, So my next question is how should I know the fee per kb for a transaction.For example if transaction is 2.0 BTC and fatest fee is 240/kb so how much in total fee I should include. @Andrew Chow

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need to know the size of the transaction, which can only be known after inputs are selected.

Comment: AFAIK, the fee is .001 BTC/kb and more the miner fee, the faster it gets confirmed.

Comment: Median transactions are of sizes 226b, which is approx 24000 Satoshi